# Angular: sort the options of a select

Tags: angularjs, sorting, drop-down-menu

The giant object array I've been blessed with is sorted by its code, rather than it's human-friendly name. I'd like it to display friendly.

**portsService:**

```
    var _getPorts = function (){
        return _portList;
    }

    var _portList = [{
            "code": "0101",
            "portOfEntry": "Portland, ME"
        }, {
            "code": "0102",
            "portOfEntry": "Bangor, ME"
        }, {
            "code": "0103",
            "portOfEntry": "Eastport, ME"
        }, {
            "code": "0104",
            "portOfEntry": "Jackman, ME"
        }, ...
```

**Controller:**

```
    vm.getPortsSelect = function () {
        vm.ports = portsService.getPorts();
    };
```

**View:**

```
<select 
        ng-model="adminManifestVm.Manifest.usPortOfArrival"  
        ng-options="port.code as port.portOfEntry for port in adminManifestVm.ports"
        name="usPortOfArrival" 
        class="form-control input-inline input-medium" 
        required>
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

There are plenty of ways to sort an object array manually. Is there an Angular way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the filter [`orderBy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

```
ng-options="port.code as port.portOfEntry for port in adminManifestVm.ports |  orderBy:'code'"
```

[**`DEMO APP`**](https://plnkr.co/edit/D3wvp3rATVDuQ6vZ1erL?p=preview)

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Marked as answer.

Comment: Tried your demo app link is dead I get ' Error loading plunk '

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the angular way is to use a [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). In this case the [`orderBy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) filter like so:

```
<select ng-model="adminManifestVm.Manifest.usPortOfArrival"  
    ng-options="port.code as port.portOfEntry for port in adminManifestVm.ports | orderBy: 'code'"
    name="usPortOfArrival" 
    class="form-control input-inline input-medium" 
    required>
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Here is the usage from the `orderBy` documentation:

`{{ orderBy_expression | orderBy : expression : reverse : comparator}}`

As you can see, it is also possible to reverse the order with the reverse boolean. The expression can also be optionally prefixed with + or - to control the sorting direction, ascending or descending. For example, '+code' or '-code' in this instance.